# Edge won't render simple CSS animation on sub-elements of SVG

Tags: css, svg

I'm applying CSS animations to SVG elements, works well with Firefox and Chrome, but won't render o Edge.. I tried to prefix it but still won't work..

I'm using simple Keyframes animation with this code:

```
@keyframes rotate {
  0%  {transform: rotate(0deg)}
  100% {transform: rotate(360deg)}
}
```

here is the demo:

http://jsbin.com/regumiruha/edit?html,css,output

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Edge does not support such things. You could try SMIL and [fakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) instead.

Comment: Edge also does not support SMIL and fakeSmile.. fakeSmile demo page itself does not animate on it.

Comment: In that case all you're left with is writing everything in javascript from first principles.

Comment: Well either that or just not supporting that in Edge, or hacking it by having two SVGs, one with the parts you need to animate and the other without; position them onto eachother, and apply animations accordingly. The animations internal to the SVGs don't work, but I'd bet element animations outside of the SVGs will.